# Detach function not updating the relationship collection

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have the following code in a test:

```
$post = factory(Post::class)->create();

$first_tag = factory(Tag::class)->create();
$second_tag = factory(Tag::class)->create();


$post->tags()->attach($first_tag);
$post->tags()->attach($second_tag);

$this->assertEquals(2, $post->tags->count());
```

Until there everything is OK but then I add the following code under the assert line:

```
$post->tags()->detach($second_tag);

$this->assertEquals(1, $post->tags->count());
```

This second assert fails and to make it work I have to manually add a line:

```
$post->tags()->detach($second_tag);
$post->load('tags');
$this->assertEquals(1, $post->tags->count());
```

Am I missing something? Do I have to manually reload the relationship everytime I detach a model in a belongsToMany relationship? Its really frustrating having to do this. Is there some reason why this is so?

Answer (score 1):

It's indeed the situation.

> The detach method will remove the appropriate record out of the
>   **intermediate table**; however, both models will remain in the database.

Therefore, even after `detaching` the `second_tag`, the `$post->tags->count` isn't up-to-date and still holds the value as if the model hadn't detached.

That's why after re-loading the relation it does work.

**In simpler words:**

There are 2 layers: one for the relations and the other one is the database. Attach/detach functions take place on the relations layer only. While `count` access the database layer which isn't aware to the modifications in the relations layer.

**How to count the tags anyway?**

It's not the prettiest solution but you can set a variable the its initial value would be the returned `count()` value and after that maintain it by increasing/decreasing it.

```
$countTags = $post->tags->count();

$post->tags()->attach($first_tag);
$countTags++;

$post->tags()->attach($second_tag);
$countTags++;

$post->tags()->detach($second_tag);
$countTags--;
```

[Source](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships)

Comment: You didn't add anything to what I explained

Comment: "Am I missing something? Do I have to manually reload the relationship everytime I detach a model in a belongsToMany relationship?" And I answered that it is the case and you're not missing a thing.

Comment: @OfirBaruch you meant attach/detach take place in database and count on the relations layer, right?

Comment: So is there some function like `count` to check the amount of records in database? I don't want to reload the relation.

Comment: Amm... you can set a variable to hold the count's value and after attaching/detaching - simply update it.

Comment: Elaborated regarding that idea in my answer.